# Customize json_decode behaviour

Tags: php, xml, json

I have a JSON string returned by a REST API which follows:

```
'{"success":true,"product":{"id":"2","category_id":"2","type":"9","name":".ch","description":"","visible":"1","domain_options":"0","stock":"0","qty":"0","autosetup":"2","subdomain":"","owndomain":"0","tax":"0","upgrades":"","sort_order":"0","client_limit":"0","rel":"Product","paytype":"DomainRegular","m_setup":"0.00","q_setup":"0.00","s_setup":"0.00","a_setup":"0.00","b_setup":"0.00","t_setup":"0.00","p4_setup":"0.00","p5_setup":"0.00","d_setup":"0.00","w_setup":"0.00","h_setup":"0.00","m":"0.00","q":"0.00","s":"0.00","a":"0.00","b":"0.00","t":"0.00","p4":"0.00","p5":"0.00","d":"0.00","w":"0.00","h":"0.00","ptype":"DomainsType","options":"3","module":"13","server":"","tlds":null,"periods":{"1":{"product_id":"2","period":"1","register":"17.00","transfer":"17.00","renew":"17.00"}},"tag_name":".ch","tag_description":"","free_domain":"0","product_id":"2","not_renew":"0","epp":true,"ns":["ns3.dfinet.ch","ns4.dfinet.ch","",""],"nsips":"|||","tld":".ch","nsip":["","","",""],"asciimode":true,"app_id":"1","app_ns1":"","app_ns2":"","app_ns3":"","app_ns4":"","app_ip1":"","app_ip2":"","app_ip3":"","app_ip4":"","emails":{"AfterRegistrarRegistration":"28","AfterRegistrarRenewal":"29","AfterRegistrarTransfer":"30","expiringDomain":"54"}},"config":false,"call":"getProductDetails","server_time":1412061849}'
```

I am trying to convert this to an object and then serve an XML for a soap webservice, what I was doing up to now was

- retrieving the result from the rest API -> convert it to object with **json_decode($obj)**
- serve the soap handle() with the converted object

The problem is that, with the following JSON, there are some properties that are "numeric" but not sequential, so the JSON convert the string to an object as follows:

```
$o = new stdClass();
$o->1 = 'a string';
```

The problem is that when soap converts object to XML, the node named **<1>** is an invalid XML markup.

What can I do to "pre-parse" the JSON and convert all of those fake objects to sequentials arrays?

**EDIT: Solution based on *dmikam* answer**

I did something cleaner based on the proposed solution:

```
function fixVariables($variables)
{
    if (!is_array($variables) && !is_object($variables)) {
        return $variables;
    }

    foreach ($variables as $k => &$variable) {

        if (is_object($variable)) {

            if (is_numeric(key($variable))) {
                $values = array();
                foreach ($variable as $value) {
                    $values[] = $value;
                }
                $variable = $values;
                unset($values);
            }
            $this->fixVariables($variable);

        } elseif (is_array($variable)) {

            if (is_numeric(key($variable))) {
                $variable = array_values($variable);
            }
            $this->fixVariables($variable);
        }
    }

    return $variables;
}
```

Comment: In your json example there are no numeric indexes. Please provide some example that uses them and which is converted wrongly for you.

Comment: there is one numeric index here: **"periods": { "1": {**, the behaviour is correct as the object representation of this json is an object with a property **{1}**, but what I'd like to do it's convert thoses "objects with numeric keys" to a sequential arrays

Comment: Ok, now I see. I'v posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you could walk through the resulting parsed object and convert all items that contains numeric indexes into arrays. The function would be something like this:

```
function fixJsonObject($obj){
    if (is_object($obj)){
        foreach(get_object_vars($obj) as $key=>$value){
            $obj->$key = fixJsonObject($obj->$key);
            if (is_numeric($key)){
                return (array)$obj;
            }
        }
    }elseif (is_array($obj)){
        foreach($obj as $key=>$value){
            $obj[$key] = fixJsonObject($obj[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $obj;        
}

$json = json_decode('{your: "json"}');
$json = fixJsonObject($json);
```

I have tested it a bitand looks like it works.

Comment: yeah I ended up with the same solution, I thought there were cleaner way to do this, but I guess it's the only thing I can do